# Apache CXF 2.2.7 and Spring 3.0

Tags: spring, cxf

Apache CXF is shipped with Spring 2.5.6, can I also use the Spring 3.0 framework without serious troubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I'm using CXF 2.2.7 and Spring 3.0.2 (The latest version) together without any issues.

Comment: Is there an up to date tutorial anywhere that you could recommend?

Comment: The CXF documentation is pretty good. It may reference older versions of spring but the configuration is still valid with Spring 3.0. http://cxf.apache.org/docs/writing-a-service-with-spring.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to exclude CXF's Spring 2.5.6 dependavies otherwise the integration test in Spring Roo will not work